# How to Shift Up Data in a CSV File

Tags: python, csv

I have this csv file that prints data like this:

| Name | Points | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 |  |  |
| Name2 |  |  |
| Name3 |  |  |
|  | 4.5 |  |
|  | 2.5 |  |
|  | 1.0 |  |
|  |  | type1 |
|  |  | type1 |
|  |  | type1 |

I would like it to print like this:

| Name | Points | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | 4.5 | type1 |
| Name2 | 2.5 | type1 |
| Name3 | 1.0 | type1 |

The only caviot to this is that the file has many sequences like this, all varying at different length ie:

| Name | Points | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 |  |  |
| Name2 |  |  |
|  | 1.0 |  |
|  | 2.0 |  |
|  |  | type1 |
|  |  | type1 |
| Name3 |  |  |
|  | 4.5 |  |
|  |  | type2 |

How would create a python program that would make the data would shift up to the uppermost empty column?

I am realitivly new to using csv files and programming in general so I have not been very succesful in any attempts. I have mostly been using ChatGPT, it has spit out some suggestions using pandas and other things, but none of them have solved my problem. Any help is appreicated, thank you!

Comment: Can you post a sample of the raw csv itself?

Comment: How does a csv file print data?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can read through the csv file using python built-in feature but keeping track of the value in each column in a separated list

```
import csv

cols = [[], [], []]
with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if row[i] != '':
                cols[i].append(row[i])
        

for i in range(len(cols[0])):
    print(','.join([cols[j][i] for j in range(3)]))
```

You can also convert the list of column values above into pandas dataframe if you like

```
import pandas as pd
for i in range(len(cols[0])):
    print(','.join([cols[j][i] for j in range(3)]))
```

Comment: Nice approach just filling the columns. You can also rotate the cols with `zip(...)`, like: `for row in zip(*cols):\n    print(row)`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve your problem is to use the pandas library in Python, which can manipulate data frames easily. Here is a sample code that might work for you:

Import pandas
import pandas as pd

Read the csv file
df = pd.read_csv(“yourfile.csv”)

Define a function to shift the values up to the uppermost empty column
def shift_up(df):

Loop through the columns
for col in df.columns: # Find the index of the first non-empty cell in the column first_non_empty = df[col].first_valid_index() # If the index is not zero, shift the values up by that amount if first_non_empty != 0: df[col] = df[col].shift(-first_non_empty)

Return the modified data frame
return df

Apply the function to the data frame
df = shift_up(df)

Write the modified data frame to a new csv file
df.to_csv(“newfile.csv”, index=False)

You can find more information about pandas and its methods from this website. I hope this helps you with your task.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas' ability to drop NaNs makes short work of this.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from io import StringIO, TextIOWrapper

import pandas as pd

csv_input = """
Name,Points,Type
name1,,
name2,,
name3,,
,4.5,
,2.5,
,1.0,
,,type1
,,type1
,,type1
"""


def shift_upwards(in_file: TextIOWrapper) -> list:
    in_df = pd.read_csv(in_file)
    return pd.DataFrame(
        {col: in_df[col].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
        for col in in_df.columns}
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(shift_upwards(StringIO(csv_input)))
```

output:

```
    Name  Points   Type
0  name1     4.5  type1
1  name2     2.5  type1
2  name3     1.0  type1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose the columns into rows with `zip` and filter out empty values with the `filter` function, and then traspose the rows back to columns with `zip`:

```
import csv
import sys
from functools import partial
from io import StringIO

file = StringIO('''Name,Points,Type
name1,,
name2,,
name3,,
,4.5,
,2.5,
,1.0,
,,type1
,,type1
,,type1''')

csv.writer(sys.stdout).writerows(
    zip(*map(partial(filter, None), zip(*csv.reader(file))))
)
```

This outputs:

```
Name,Points,Type
name1,4.5,type1
name2,2.5,type1
name3,1.0,type1
```